# How to find the idle intervals in integer programming?

Tags: integer-programming, constraint

I have a scheduling problem with one machine and one job. I defined a binary variable $z_t$ that is 1 iff the job is scheduled at time $t$ (the job can be served in multiple times that are not consecutive). I would like to find the intervals where the machine is idle.

For example, if the job is scheduled at $t=1$, $t=4$, $t=8$, and $t=11$, then the machine is idle between $t=2$ and $t=3$, which gives an interval of length $2$. It is idle between $t=5$ and $t=7$, which gives an interval of length $3$. And, it is idle between $t=9$ and $t=10$, which gives an interval of length $2$.

How can I write this using the variable $z_t$? Say, I would like to enforce a constraint that says that the machine must be idle for intervals whose length are shorter than a threshold?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To disallow an idle interval of length $k$, you want to enforce the logical proposition
$$\neg \bigwedge_{t=s}^{s+k-1} \neg z_t,$$
equivalently,
$$\bigvee_{t=s}^{s+k-1} z_t,$$
for each starting time $s$.
You can do this via linear constraints
$$\sum_{t=s}^{s+k-1} z_t \ge 1.$$

To instead count the number of idle intervals of length $\ge k$,
introduce another binary variable, say $x_s$, that will indicate the start of the interval.  To enforce 
$$x_s\implies \left(z_{s-1} \land \bigwedge_{t=s}^{s+k-1} \neg z_t\right),$$
impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
x_s &\le z_{s-1} &&\text{for all $s$}\\
x_s &\le 1- z_t &&\text{for all $s$, $t\in\{s,\dots,s+k-1\}$}\\
\end{align}
To enforce the converse
$$\left(z_{s-1} \land \bigwedge_{t=s}^{s+k-1} \neg z_t\right)\implies x_s,$$
impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
z_{s-1} + \sum_{t=s}^{s+k-1} (1 - z_t) - k &\le x_s &&\text{for all $s$}
\end{align}
Now $\sum_s x_s$ counts the number of idle intervals of length $\ge k$.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to count the number of idle intervals that have length more than a threshold?

Comment: I updated the answer to include this additional information.